# Big Amount of Data on a PC?

Tags: python-3.x, database, apache-spark

Hello I want to deal with a big amount of data of 1 billions rows and 23 columns. But in pandas I cannot even read the data. So how can I handle this data on my computer which is Dell XPS 9570. Can I use spark for that? Any advice to deal with it on my PC?

Thank you

Comment: A lot of db interfaces are implemented in python. As standard Python 3 comes with `sqlite3` which is on disk relational database. If you don't need all the data at once this could be way to go. More [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html)

Comment: spark is build for distributed environment, you can run it on local doesn't mean you should. So you can give it a try. It has few tricks (i.e. lazy evolution) which might help. But not sureity.

Answer (score 0):

Basically for handling large amount of data you have to use big data tool like `Hadoop` or `Apache Spark`. You can use `pyspark` which is combination of python and spark having high efficiency for data processing.

I suggest, if you have flat file format then used ORC file format for processing data into pyspark which improve your performance efficiency.

Comment: Is is logical to use spark on mu just one personal laptop because spark is better on several nodes as far as I know?

Comment: If you have spark multi node cluster than you can take advantage of distributed system but in single node spark is also efficient because apache spark is specially build for Big data. It performs in memory computation so it's more efficient than python.